# What is the Settings_ShellFeatureRecord table in an Orchard database? And is it expected behaviour to have what appears to be repeating values in it?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

After having a look around the Orchard CMS database, I noticed the table `Settings_ShellFeatureRecord`. This table contains 965 rows, a lot of which appear to be duplicates.

Here is a snapshot of some of the data in this table:

[image]

There appears to be a lot of repeated feature names here. Is this expected? If not, then what could be causing this?